# How to set up auto transfer of baking and endorsement rewards to respective delegation accounts?

Tags: baker, transfer, rewards, payment

I am running a baker node with few delegations. I have started receiving rewards in my baking account. Now I want to autopay the rewards share back to delegation accounts and avoid the manual work here?
Is there any script available for this which i can run on my baker node?

Answer (score 3):

Although there are a couple of scripts that will allow bakers to do auto payments, I would recommend you to try TAPS (Tezos Automatic Payment System). It is a web based solution with a complete GUI, allowing you to set up a scheduled task that will fetch tzScan.io each hour to detect a cycle change, by which it will loop through your delegators, calculate the charged fee and make the transfers without any interference. TAPS will also allow you to customize a fee for each delegator and will save a payment history. It offers PDF reports too. The resources for payments can be obtained from your node account or from a TAPS internal native wallet. You may find more info about TAPS on [this link](https://medium.com/coinmonks/taps-1-0-released-19aff984f484).